# Save in Sublime Text with Another Extension

Tags: file, syntax, save, sublimetext, file-extension

In Sublime Text 2 & 3, whenever I save a file with one extension, or without an extension, then save it with another extension later, the syntax colors seem to stay with the first extension. For example, when I save what I mean to be a JavaScript or PHP file without an extension by accident, then `Save As` with the correct extension, the text stays all black.

Is this supposed to happen? Is it because the file isn't actually saved as the 2nd extension the next time? Most importantly, is there a way to save the file with the correct extension without creating a new file & copying all the text over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the syntax manually as follows.[image: set syntax]

click `HTML` and you will see all the syntaxes, you may choose whatever you want, or you can do it in the `command palette` by type `ctrl+shify+P` and type `syntax` and you can do the same thing.

Comment: If Sublime Text does this automatically when you save the first time, depending on the extension, how come when you change the extension it doesn't change the syntax automatically? That was part of my question.

Comment: for me, when I save as the correct file extension, it will open the new file with the right syntax for me. btw, I'm using sublime text 3

Comment: Weird, it's doing it now, but it wasn't before. I wonder what happened? Ah well, it's not too hard to copy/paste into another file if it ever happens again. Thanks, I'll close this soon.